# Keep getting ERROR [org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.InvocationHandlerJAXWS]

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, ejb

Currently I am trying to work on my web service to generate tac number.

This is ejb TacGenerator.java

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import com.TacEntity.Tac;
public class TacGenerator1{

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "TacDB")
private EntityManager em4;

    public String generate(String tacId, String data){


        //Creating Date
        Date date = new Date();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);



        //Generating TacNumber      
        int num;
        String tacNum;
        num = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * (999999 + 1));
        tacNum = String.format("%06d", num);

        //Placing in database
        Tac tac = new Tac();
        tac.setTacId(tacId.replace(' ', '+'));
        tac.setTacData(data.replace(' ', '+'));
        tac.setTacNum(tacNum);
        tac.setTacCrdate(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
        tac.setTacExdate(new Timestamp(cal.getTime().getTime()));
        em4.persist(tac);

        return tac.getTacNum();
    }


       }
```

and this is my webservice for TacGenerator.java

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.nisa.javabrains.business.TacGenerator1;


@WebService
public class TacGeneratorWebServices {

TacGenerator1 tacNumber = new TacGenerator1();

@WebMethod  
public String generate(String tacId, String data){
    return tacNumber.generate(tacId, data);
}

  }
```

The code return the tac number nicely if I only put the generating tac number code, but when I add the creating date, and placing in database codes, the web service is not working, and return me this error `javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: com/TacEntity/Tac`

and this is the Tac.java (my database class, com/TacEntity/Tac)

```
package com.TacEntity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
//import javax.xml.ws.soap.*;


/**
 * The persistent class for the tacs database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="tacs")
@NamedQuery(name="Tac.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM Tac t")
public class Tac implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="tac_id")
private String tacId;

@Column(name="tac_crdate")
private Timestamp tacCrdate;

@Column(name="tac_data")
private String tacData;

@Column(name="tac_exdate")
private Timestamp tacExdate;

@Column(name="tac_num")
private String tacNum;

public Tac() {
}

public String getTacId() {
    return this.tacId;
}

public void setTacId(String tacId) {
    this.tacId = tacId;
}

public Timestamp getTacCrdate() {
    return this.tacCrdate;
}

public void setTacCrdate(Timestamp tacCrdate) {
    this.tacCrdate = tacCrdate;
}

public String getTacData() {
    return this.tacData;
}

public void setTacData(String tacData) {
    this.tacData = tacData;
}

public Timestamp getTacExdate() {
    return this.tacExdate;
}

public void setTacExdate(Timestamp tacExdate) {
    this.tacExdate = tacExdate;
}

public String getTacNum() {
    return this.tacNum;
}

public void setTacNum(String tacNum) {
    this.tacNum = tacNum;
}

    }
```

ok the Stack trace is here..

```
 12:39:40,784 ERROR [org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.InvocationHandlerJAXWS] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Method invocation failed with exception: null: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

 [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
atorg.jboss.ws.common.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandlerJSE.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandlerJSE.java:111)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker._invokeInternal(JBossWSInvoker.java:181)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:127)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:91)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:169)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:87)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:135)
at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.0.3.GA.jar:2.0.3.GA]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]

Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Tac cannot be resolved to a type
Tac cannot be resolved to a type
Timestamp cannot be resolved to a type
Timestamp cannot be resolved to a type

at org.nisa.javabrains.business.TacGenerator1.generate(TacGenerator1.java:38) [classes:]
at org.nisa.javabrains.TacGeneratorWebServices.generate(TacGeneratorWebServices.java:18) [classes:]
... 39 more




 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Application {http://javabrains.nisa.org/}TacGeneratorWebServicesService#{http://javabrains.nisa.org/}generate has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Tac cannot be resolved to a type
Tac cannot be resolved to a type
Timestamp cannot be resolved to a type
Timestamp cannot be resolved to a type

at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.createFault(JBossWSInvoker.java:246)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker._invokeInternal(JBossWSInvoker.java:201)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:127)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:91)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:169)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:87)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:135)
at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.0.3.GA.jar:2.0.3.GA]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Tac cannot be resolved to a type
Tac cannot be resolved to a type
Timestamp cannot be resolved to a type
Timestamp cannot be resolved to a type

at org.nisa.javabrains.business.TacGenerator1.generate(TacGenerator1.java:38) [classes:]
at org.nisa.javabrains.TacGeneratorWebServices.generate(TacGeneratorWebServices.java:18) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
at org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandlerJSE.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandlerJSE.java:111)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker._invokeInternal(JBossWSInvoker.java:181)
... 33 more
```

So do I need to do something in my database class,Tac? should there be any web service annotation in the file ? Really need a help now .I tried to look the solution , but really could not catch it.

Thanks :D

Comment: I'm not sure of this (which is why it's just a comment) but I don't think SOAP lets you transmit dates and times as a `Timestamp`.  I would suggest storing them as the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970, which you can get using the `getTime()` method.  Please let me know if that works and I'll convert this comment to an answer.

Comment: Thank you for replying :D . I did as you said, but it is still not working, and getting the same error ..javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: com/TacEntity/Tac..

Comment: OK.  You said that you had a version without the error, then you added in the created date, and you added in the database code, and then the error started happening.  Does it work if you have the created date but not the database code?  How about the other way around?  Can you narrow down which feature is causing the problem?

Comment: oh yes,it work fine if I put the create date and generating tac number code(it will return the tac number as I wanted) , but the error occur when I put the database code(which I wanted to store the the tac number and the date n time it is created).So I think the problem is with the database code

Comment: OK, so can you add the database code bit by bit - maybe a line at a time - or something like that, to see which line causes the problem?

Comment: ok, I tried to put the first code, Tac tac = new Tac();.... em4.persist(tac); return tac.getTacNum();, an try to run it, same error. even it is the first code of the databse, give me error.Do you think that I need to make changes in my database file?...adding web services or something perhaps?--thinking--

Comment: If you show the entire stack trace we will get a better idea of what is actually going wrong.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand,what do you mean entire stack trace?

Comment: Steve means the entire error message, including everything that appears below it, not just the first line of it.

Comment: ok I have put the stack trace in the question ...any ideas what s going on? ...

Comment: uh I am still not able to solve it..huhuh anyone? :(